# Aerator/Diffusor for irregular bathroom faucet

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink

My bathroom sink's water flow is too high at max output, and the sink is fairly flat. This causes water to splash all over the place when it hits the sink.

The faucet is a Toto, flat-shaped, with a slot-shaped output hole, so I can't install a standard aerator. About an inch back from the hole, there is a circular unscrewable thing on the underside of the faucet. I have not been able to unscrew it so far. Is this where an aerator might go (or currently is)?, or do I need to DIY something onto the slot-shaped hole?

Pics:
https://imgur.com/gallery/P4ypcdD

Comment: You could put an inline flow regulator on the supply lines as a different approach. Unless you [edit] in a picture, only some vanishingly small set of people that have the same faucet and are answering questions here have any idea what the *circular unscrewable thing* is. Presumably if you search for Toto <model name of faucet> aerator you'll either find results or not - or you could contact Toto and ask.

Comment: You might be able to find an aerator for your faucet but it's a long shot - some faucets don't have them. I suggest that you simply back off the supply line shutoff valves under the sink a half turn or so, so they are not on full. This will reduce the pressure to a more desirable level. You might have to play with the hot and cold shutoffs to equalize the pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a flow regulator.  It can be as simple as a inline valve that you can adjust.  I cant find the right phrase to google.  In our part of the world it is common for basins and sinks to have them for emergency turn off.

Photos from under my sink, one for each line (cold and hot). These are right angle ones.  But you can get inline versions too.

[image]

[image]